# AWS Lambda not reading query parameters from API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

For the following lambda function using Lambda-Proxy integration using the URL

```
/api/random?min=1&max=10
```

My code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let min = event.queryStringParameters.min
    let max = event.queryStringParameters.max
    console.log("min", min)
    console.log("max",max)
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(Math.floor(Math.random()*max)+min),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Execution fails with the following error:

> ```
> Response:
> {
>   "errorType": "TypeError",
>   "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'min' of undefined",
>   "trace": [
>     "TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined",
>     "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:3:43)",
>     "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:65:25)",
>     "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"
>   ]
> }
> ```

Logging the event using `JSON.stringify(event)` returns the correct parameters:

> ```
> {"min":"1","max":"10"}
> ```

Comment: Ever find a fix for this?

Comment: did you ever sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

> Logging the event using JSON.stringify(event) returns the correct
>   parameters:
>
> {"min":"1","max":"10"}

You Lambda event does not seem to have `queryStringParameters` property attached. You either need to add it in the event or modify code to:

```
let { min, max } = event
```

Comment: event has the following "queryStringParameters": {
"max": "10",
"min": "1"
}. your suggestion causes it to retutn mull everytime.

Comment: it does not match with what you have put in the question. `Logging the event using JSON.stringify(event) returns the correct parameters: {"min":"1","max":"10"}`

Comment: what's the fix?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a bug in the function I called later in the code(that unrelated to the queryString),
when I put it in a comment, the error disappeared !.